# Launching MAMP using LaunchDaemon not working in Mavericks

Tags: launchd, mamp

I followed the instructions from this page: http://blog.dannykey.com/automatically-launch-mamp-on-start-up/ to try to get MAMP starting at system start-up without a user logging in. I did this before without a hitch before updating to Mavericks but it was long ago and I can't remember if I did anything differently.

My problem is that the launch daemon is not starting MAMP.

I first ran launchctl list to see if launchd was at least reading my plists:

```
sudo launchctl list | grep mamp
```

sometimes it returns:

```
74  -   info.mamp.start.mysql
-   0   info.mamp.start.apache
```

meaning mysql started, but not apache. Other times, without any seeming regularity it returns:

```
-   3   info.mamp.start.mysql
-   0   info.mamp.start.apache
```

which seems to mean that mysql started but exited with an error code.

If I run:

```
sudo launchctl start info.mamp.start.apache
sudo launchctl start info.mamp.start.mysql
```

both servers start and run fine. So it seems that my plist is not to blame. Here is the apache plist I used (I copy/pasted from the link above, similarly with the mysql plist):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>info.mamp.start.apache</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl</string>
      <string>start</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

What is the next step to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That plist doesn't seem to work anymore. This one works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>info.mamp.start.apache</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl</string>
      <string>-f</string>
      <string>/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/httpd.conf</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```